# Server uptime before it crashed

Tags: linux

My Linux Server has crashed due to an unknown reason. I need to find out what time the server stopped working due to this issue.

Is there anyway to find exactly what time it was before the server crashed?

As per my findings, I could only see this `Hardware error` message in `/var/log/messages`.

```
Oct 20 15:19:26 localhost kernel: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged

Oct 20 15:49:26 localhost kernel: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

Comment: Try /var/log/kern.log (on ubuntu/debian). It is more likely to have info about a crash.

Comment: Try `last reboot`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21646/cant-explain-crash-entries-in-output-of-the-last-command